# Difference between variable assigning and literal constant?

Tags: c++, c, variables, types, constants

I am bit confused about assigning a value to variable and literal constants.

For example:

```
int age = 20;
```

`age` is a variable, and `20` is the value assigned to it.

And:

```
int AGE = 20;
```

`AGE` is literal constant, `20` is the value assigned to it.

What is the difference? Will constants take the same two bytes in main memory as variables?

Comment: `int AGE = 20; "AGE" is literal constant,`...why's so?

Comment: In your question, `int ages = 20` and `int AGE = 20` is the same. Only difference I see the variable name :D

Comment: In second version, did you mean `#define AGE 20`?

Comment: `const int age = 20;`would be different, `#define AGE 20` would be very different

Comment: Also, on most modern systems an `int` variable will consume four bytes of memory.  However a `const int` might take none.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confused indeed:

```
 int age = 20;
```

assigns integer value 20 to a variable `age`.

```
int AGE = 20;
```

assigns integer value 20 to a variable `AGE`.

There's no difference.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int AGE = 20;
> ```
>
> AGE is literal constant, 20 is the value assigned to it.

No, `AGE` is a variable, same as `age` (but with a different name).

To declare a constant:

```
const int AGE = 20;
```

To use a literal constant directly (**this is discouraged in modern C++**):

```
#define AGE 20 // every time you use AGE, the literal "20" will be used instead
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in your case:

```
int age = 20;
```

is a variable named "age" with value 20.

```
int AGE = 20;
```

is a variable named "AGE" with value 20.

If you want to declare a constant with a specific type in your code using `const` prefix:

```
const int AGE = 20;
```

In other case, you can use the `#define` preprocessor:

```
#define AGE 20;
```

The difference between a variable and a constant (or literal constant) is that the constant, once defined, you cannot change its value.

Answer (score 1):

> AGE is literal constant, 20 is the value assigned to it.

Incorrect!

You cannot assign a value to a literal constant.  The literal constant is the value assigned to the variable.

I got confused originally because my textbook and online resources give "int mynum = 20;" as an example of a literal constant and "int anum = 20;" as an example of a variable.

It wasn't until I  read it over 100 times that I realized that both "mynum" and "anum" are variables whereas 20 is the literal constant.

Answer (score 0):

Constant literals are like regular variables, occupy same size. The only difference is that the value of constant variable cannot be altered. We use the key word `const` to indicate a constant variable

```
const int AGE=20;
```

we capitalize the constant variable just to distinguish it from regular variables.

Comment: a literal constant may take no space whatsoever, if the compiler substitutes the constant directly into the assembly instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int AGE = 20;
```

> AGE is literal constant, 20 is the value assigned to it.

AGE is just a variable name and 20 is a literal constant. More information http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/